# Pandas dataframe (non-unique multi-index) to html table with CSS styling attribute error

Tags: python, html, css, pandas

I am trying to export a pandas dataframe to a html table with custom CSS coloring options using a pandas `Style` object. I have read through the examples listed here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html

I understand that I need to create a style object and then render that object.

My issue is that my specific table is raising an exception: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'`. My table is different from the example tables in the *link* because it contains a non-unique multi-index.

The simplest example of this `ValueError`can be created with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



myTable = pd.DataFrame({ 'Class': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                    'First' : ['John', 'Lenny', 'Bill', 'Ryan', 'James'],
                    'Last': ['McGee', 'Beir', 'Schwarts', 'Mulroney', 'Buchura'],
                    'Grade': [76, 87, 46, 83, 98],
                    'StudentID': [2828, 2673, 7811, 2828, 1782]})

myTable.set_index(['Class', 'StudentID'], inplace=True)
myTable = myTable[['First', 'Last', 'Grade']] 

s = myTable.style

html = s.render()

text_file = open('df.html', "w")
text_file.write(s)
text_file.close()
```

Notice that the table contains a non-unique index (1st and 4th row).

Moreover, if I get rid of the non-uniqueness, another exception is raised: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'`. The example below will produce that error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



myTable = pd.DataFrame({ 'Class': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                    'First' : ['John', 'Lenny', 'Bill', 'Ryan', 'James'],
                    'Last': ['McGee', 'Beir', 'Schwarts', 'Mulroney', 'Buchura'],
                    'Grade': [76, 87, 46, 83, 98],
                    'StudentID': [2828, 2673, 7811, 2878, 1782]})

myTable.set_index(['Class', 'StudentID'], inplace=True)
myTable = myTable[['First', 'Last', 'Grade']] 

s = myTable.style

html = s.render()

text_file = open('df.html', "w")
text_file.write(s)
text_file.close()
```

How does one get around these errors? Why would pandas limit styling options to unique 1-dimensional index `DataFrames`?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error in your second example.

Comment: @TedPetrou Strange, are you using Python 3.5? What about the first error?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because when you use [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) and then change it to HTML, you will see that additional empty headers and multiple header rows are created.

Style is not written for MultiIndexing. You will likely need to replace data inside your rendered HTML instead of using pandas Style.

You also don't have anything to style ... You sure you don't just need .to_html() added?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myTable = pd.DataFrame({ 'Class': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                'First' : ['John', 'Lenny', 'Bill', 'Ryan', 'James'],
                'Last': ['McGee', 'Beir', 'Schwarts', 'Mulroney', 'Buchura'],
                'Grade': [76, 87, 46, 83, 98],
                'StudentID': [2828, 2673, 7811, 2878, 1782]})

myTable.set_index(['Class', 'StudentID'], inplace=True)
myTable = myTable[['First', 'Last', 'Grade']] 

html = myTable.to_html()

text_file = open('df.html', "w")
text_file.write(html)
text_file.close()
```

## OPTION 2

I also saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738175/pandas-style-object-with-multi-index) for something similar and a suggestion was to use [pd.IndexSlice](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

## OPTION 3

Changing your CSS styles

At the beginning of your HTML, you can add something like:

```
<style>
table {text-align: center;}
table thead th {text-align: center;}
</style>
```