# Pandas style object with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, styles, subset, multi-index

I am formatting a pandas dataframe with styler to highlight columns and format numbers. I also want to apply multi-index for more clear, pleasant and easy to read. Since I apply Styler to subset of columns it does not work work with the multi-index.

Example:

```
arrays = [np.hstack([['One']*2, ['Two']*2]) , ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)
data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
data.columns = columns 
import seaborn as sns
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
data.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=['A'])
```

Is there a way to subset the columns so the styler can work. According to the below sources this is implemented but there is not examples so it is hard to me to understand how to apply it:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.formats.style.Styler.html
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11655

thank you !

Answer (score 22):

I think you can use [pd.IndexSlice[...]](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) method:

```
data.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'A']])
```

Demo:

```
In [5]: data.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'A']]]
Out[5]:
        One
          A
0 -0.808483
1  0.009371
2  0.977138
3 -0.875554
4 -0.052424

In [6]: data
Out[6]:
        One                 Two
          A         B         C         D
0 -0.808483 -2.280683  0.576145  0.649688
1  0.009371  0.721510  1.013764 -0.157493
2  0.977138  1.441392  1.718618 -0.320826
3 -0.875554 -1.060507  1.457075  0.570195
4 -0.052424 -0.742842 -0.203830 -1.202091
```

in Jupyter:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I educated myself on slicing multi-indices. Something I have overlooked in pandas.

Comment: I get `TypeError: unhashable type: slice` on Pandas 0.24.2 :(

Comment: @krubo, do you get this error for the __same__ dataset?

Comment: Yes, I have `import pandas as pd` then `import numpy as np` then OP's code (except the last line), then your answer line, and I get the error.  Meanwhile, cabbagetreecustard's answer works fine but makes my code messy because I don't know the hierarchy ahead of time.

Comment: May I know how to make the frames around the cells? Answers from others did not show those frames

Answer (score 11):

Here, is another way:

```
data.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=data.columns.get_loc_level('A', level=1)[0])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works for me on Pandas 0.24.2 with Python 3.6.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you know what the hierarchy of the index is, for example that 'A' is under 'One' you can use a tuple to reference the column.

```
data.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=[('One','A')])
```

Then the table will be displayed as above.

Should you want to style more than one column with a multi-index you need to provide a list of tuples ie

```
arrays = [np.hstack([['One']*2, ['Two']*2]) , ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)
data =  pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
data.columns = columns 
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
data.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=[('One','A'),('Two','C')])
```

Displays like this

[image: Jupyter output]

Answer (score 3):

For the original question:

```py
data.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm,
                               subset=[c for c in data.columns if c[1] == 'A'])
```

[image]

You could check some condition, substring for example:

```py
data.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm,
                               subset=[c for c in data.columns if 'T' in c[0]])
```

[image]

Or pass a list of subcolumns:

```py
data.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, 
                               subset=[c for c in data.columns if c[1] in ('A', 'C')])
```

[image]