# Panda styler on multiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to style a panda DataFrame on a certain index of a multiIndex. Normally, pd.IndexSlice should work according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41738175) answer.

However, as shown below, this does not seem to work:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
cv = ['data1_1','data1_2','data1_3']
param = ['data2_1', 'data2_2']
combi = tuple(itertools.product(cv,param))
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(combi)
myData = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4,6), dtype=bool)*False, columns = columns)

myData.iloc[0,0] = True

def highligh(val):
    if val == True:
        color = 'red'
    else:
        color = 'white'
    return 'background-color: {}'.format(color)

myColoredData = myData.style.apply(highligh, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'data2_2']])


import seaborn as sns
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
myColoredData2 = myData.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'data2_2']])

myData.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'data2_2']]]

myColoredData.to_excel('colored.xlsx')
myColoredData2.to_excel('colored2.xlsx')
```

The `to_excel` method is throwing me an error:

> unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: I tried to recreate your example, and it break broke after the `myColoredData = myData.style.apply(highligh, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'data2_2']])` part, when I tried to display `myColoredData`

Comment: Seems to be a pandas styler issue as `myData.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'data2_2']]]` works...

Answer (score 0):

As of now, this does not seem to work, as [stated here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25858):

> Note that this indexer previously worked in pandas version 0.22, but a regression has been introduced in 0.24.2

Interestingly, I had a similar issue with 0.24.2 but not with 0.23.4.